# Data management in Angular - referencing other objects in classes with lots of repeating information

Tags: javascript, angular

I don't really know what to call this, but I am wondering if there's a name for this technique/some resources teaching how to do it. I want to pass data from an API on the backend into Angular, and I want to have modular objects to have as child properties objects that will be repeated a lot. For example, having 100 survey responses, and each survey response points to one of 10 questions.

It would be inefficient to have the backend pass the same 10 questions back with each survey answer, there would be a lot of repeats. It would make more sense to pass back the 10 questions, and then pass the 100 survey responses with a numeric pointer to the 10 questions. How would I then handle that on the frontend? Would the service match up the questions to the answers? Would Javascript store these objects as references and not create a bunch of unneeded memory? Very importantly: If I modified one of the questions on one of the answer objects, would it update that question on all of the other answer objects?

```
export class Answer {
    id: number;
    response: number;
    question: Question;
}

export class Question {
    id: number;
    question: string;
}
```

Let me know if I can provide any more info. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you change `Answer` like this:

```
  export class Answer {
    id: number;
    response: number;
    questionId: number;
}
```

You solve the first problem. Then you load in the UI the `Question` according to `id`.

The second part of your question is a bit abstract. It depends on the way you display the data if the view will be updated anywhere upon change. If you structure the view directly from the API response the answer is no. If you map the response as a form (ie. `ReactiveForm`) then yes but you will need some extra tinkering.

In general asking so many questions in one post is a bit hard to answer :)

Answer (score 1):

> What you're trying to do is to mimic a relational database in the frontend. This is possible and the needed effort, in your case, is relatively small.

I'd do it this way, referring to you given objects.

Do not put in the answer id in the answer object but the answer itself. The rest can stay as it is.

```
export class Answer {
    id: number;
    response: string;
    questionId: number;
}

export class Question {
    id: number;
    question: string;
}
```

Put the objects into Arrays.

```
private questions: Array<Question> = [];
private answers: Array<Answer> = [];
```

Here is a simple example of how to relate answers and questions by their ids.

```
constructor() { 

    const question: Question = new Question(); 
    question.id = 1000;
    question.question = 'What?';
    this.questions.push(question);

    question.id = 1001;
    question.question = 'Who?';
    this.questions.push(question);

    question.id = 1002;
    question.question = 'Why?';
    this.questions.push(question);

    const answer: Answer = new Answer();
    answer.id = 10000;
    answer.questionId = 1000;
    answer.response = 'That I';
    this.answers.push(answer);

    answer.id = 10001;
    answer.questionId = 1000;
    answer.response = 'That II';
    this.answers.push(answer);

    answer.id = 10002;
    answer.questionId = 1000;
    answer.response = 'That III';
    this.answers.push(answer);

    answer.id = 10003;
    answer.questionId = 1001;
    answer.response = 'Me';
    this.answers.push(answer);

    answer.id = 10004;
    answer.questionId = 1001;
    answer.response = 'You';
    this.answers.push(answer);

    answer.id = 10005;
    answer.questionId = 1001;
    answer.response = 'Him';
    this.answers.push(answer);

}
```

As you can see, you can relate as much answers as you want to a given question. And that's it.

> What you now need is a service that handles the relations. It has to contain all the methods that do tasks like `fetchQuestionById(id: number)` and so on.
>
> As you have only 100 answers and 10 questions instead of 100 answers and 1000 questions, the used memory won't be a problem at all.
>
> Changing a question at runtime will implicitly update all following service calls. Due to the fact that you will change the questions directly in the array, every call to the service will then provide the changed question immediately.